# UserDefaults is NOT keeping data saved after app is closed and re-opened

Tags: swift, userdefaults

A problem that I am currently encountering is that the `recordData` value does not remain saved if I leave the app and come back. It does remain saved if I play the game again without closing the app.

If I close and reopen the app, ant new `score` will replace the `recordData`, and thus, update the `highScoreLabel1.text` with the new `score`. This will occur even if the new `score` is a lesser value than the previously saved `recordData` value.  Please note that the `highScoreLabel1.text` does show the proper High Score when the app is re-opened. It just doesn't keep it after any new `score` is made. So, basically its seems like `UserDefaults` is only working while the app is open and is not persisting after the app is closed and re-opened. I probably need something in `AppDelegate`. Any suggestions?

Here's my `highScore` and `UserDefaults` code:

```
var recordData = 0

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    highScoreLabel1A.text = String(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Record1A"))
}

func highScore() {
    guard gameMode == 0, let score = Int(scoreLabel.text!), score > recordData else { return }
    recordData = score
    UserDefaults.standard.set(recordData, forKey: "Record1A")
    highScoreLabel1B.text = String(recordData)
}
```

Comment: Looks like recordData will always be 0 when you start the app. Therefore, any score will be higher and will be written to UserDefaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a line in `viewWillAppear` that will set `recordData` to the previously saved High Score ...

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // high score code
    highScoreLabel1A.text = String(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Record1A"))

    // This code will set recordData to the previously saved High Score value, thus avoiding "0"
    recordData = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Record1A")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UserDefaults` IS keeping the data, but you set only the text label and not the variable `recordData`.

Replace `viewWillAppear` with

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    recordData = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Record1A")
    highScoreLabel1A.text = String(recordData)
}
```